# How to display the multiple element inside a tag in xml using JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I need to get the text of an element from a xml tag. The element can be repeated multiple times inside the same tag. I am able to get the number of occurrences of an element inside the tag, but I am not able to display the text. I am doing something like this

```
            getTo=$(this).find('TO');//.text();
            alert("the lenght is ::"+getTo.length);
            getToNode=$(this).children('TO').text();
```

The TO Element is repeated inside the tag. getTo.length gives me the number of occurrences inside the tag. Now I want to display their text with a separator between the text. Above code gives me the text of each and every element all together.

Please let me know the way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the each function would help you.

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: I want to try something like this. Lets say i have a for loop and for there are several html divs created such as window1, window2 and so on. Now i want to find these all windows keeping in a for loop. I am doing something like this, but its not working for me.

for connectWindow = 1 to n
var windo = "window"+connectWindow;
var too = "to"+connectWindow;
alert("Making connections" + windo +to)
$("div#windo").find('p#too').each(function(){

var name = $(this).text();
//display_function(name,country);
alert("Name is :::"+name);
});

How would I do this?